# How to fill a new data frame based on the value and the results of an calculus integrating this very value?

Tags: r

For graphical purpose, I want to create a new data frame with two columns.
The first column is the dose of the treatment received (i; 10 grammes up to 200  grammes).
The second column must be filed with the result of a calculus corresponding to the value of the dose received, id est the percentage of patients developing the disease according the corresponding dose which is given by the formula  below:

The dose is extracted from a much larger dataset (data_fcpa) of more than 1 000 rows (patients).

`percent_i <- round (prop.table (table (data_fcpa $ n_chir_act [data_fcpa $ cyproterone_dose > i] > 1))[2] * 100, 1)`

I know how to create a new data (df) with the doses I want to explore:

```
df <- data.frame (dose <- seq (10, 200, by = 10))
names (df) <- c("cpa_dose")
> df
   cpa_dose
1        10
2        20
3        30
4        40
5        50
6        60
7        70
8        80
9        90
10      100
11      110
12      120
13      130
14      140
15      150
16      160
17      170
18      180
19      190
20      200
```

For example for a dose of 10 grammes the result is:

```
> round (prop.table (table (data_fcpa $ n_chir_act [data_fcpa $ cyproterone_dose > 10] > 1))[2] * 100, 1)
TRUE 
11.7
```

I suspect that a loop is needed to produce an output alike the little example provided below but, I have no idea of how to do it.

```
 cpa_dose percentage
1      10       11.7
2      20       
3      30       
4      40
```

Any suggestion are welcomed.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are describing a a situation where you want to show predicted effects from a statistical model? In that case, `ggeffects` is your best friend.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggeffects)


lm(mpg ~ hp,mtcars) %>% 
  ggpredict() %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

[image]

Btw, in order to answer your question it's required to provide some data and show what you have tried.